# VueJs Async Api Data best practice

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, load

I am building a headless SPA SSR in NuxtJs, and I am wondering what best practices is for making sure that the application only loads if connection has been established to the remote API.

This is currently my index.vue component:

```html
<template>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>{{site.meta.title}}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Meta from '../classes/api/General/Meta'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      meta: null
    }
  },
  created () {
    Meta.getMeta().then((response) => {
      this.meta = response.data
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

This sometimes resolves in that `site.meta.title` is undefined because the site is loading before the api data has been initialised. And yes, `site.meta.title` is defined under the hood in the api. So. Next step I was thinking was using async like following script:

```js
<script>
import Meta from '../classes/api/General/Meta'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      meta: null
    }
  },
  async created () {
    await Meta.getMeta().then((response) => {
      this.meta = response.data
      console.log(response.data.site.logo)
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Though this doesn't help anyway.

But with `v-if="meta"` it does help. Though: now it seems that Axios is not rendering the content in the code (ssr) anymore.

Comment: What is a `headless SPA SSR` ? Headless means without a front-end, like a headless CMS, here it's Nuxt so you do have a front-end. An SPA + SSR app is called _universal app_ or even isomorphic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.log` is not something that you can really trust 100% of the time for async debugging tbh.
`console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()))` can help a bit more but it's still have some drawbacks sometimes.

As for best practices, both `beforeCreate` and `created` do run on both sides (server + client) so it's fine to use those. You can also use `asyncData` and the new `fetch` (it's a Nuxt hook, not the actual [*fetch API*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)).

Beware of using the `async/await` syntax properly tho (no need for `then` here):

```js
async created() {
  const response = await Meta.getMeta()
  this.meta = response.data
  console.log(this.meta)
}
```

Also, with proper `async/await`, this one will never happen actually

> because the site is loading before the api data has been initialised

You can read a bit more about the Nuxt lifecycle here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle

I'd recommend usually going the `async fetch()` way (non blocking, nice helpers), or `async asyncData()` if you need a blocking method. Middlewares can also be useful to make the whole process more flexible around your application.

You can get the whole explanation between the differences of `fetch` vs `asyncData` here: https://nuxtjs.org/blog/understanding-how-fetch-works-in-nuxt-2-12/

And if you want to have an example on how to use `fetch` in a real world scenario, you can read this one: https://nuxtjs.org/blog/build-dev-to-clone-with-nuxt-new-fetch/

Answer (score 1):

So, It turns out that I got this the completely wrong way around.
In the newest nuxt versions, async fetch method is now included (build in).

With this, all rendering etc works fine and as expected.
My ended working code looks like this now:

```js
<script>
export default {
  async fetch () {
    this.meta = await fetch(
      'https://testurl.com/meta'
    ).then(res => res.json())
  },
  data () {
    return {
      meta: null
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And the beauty with fetch, is that you can add listeners" like so:

```html
<p v-if="$fetchState.pending">Fetching site</p>
<p v-else-if="$fetchState.error">Error happened</p>
<p>This content will be rendered server side even though waiting time</p>
```

I'm just posting this because my original question was a bit miss explained, and hope to help somebody else.

**Edit:**
I have marked kissu as answer (did see the post after i created this one), because it was explained so nice and well done!
Thanks :-)