# Difference between axios response and network response

Tags: vuejs2, axios, vuex

I have an issue with an axios call, here is the result of my network tab :

[image: Edge Network tab]

I log the response immediatly after axios response :

[image: Console log after axios response]

Here is the result of the console log :

[image]

As you can see the scope.label value of the last element of subscriptions is different between network tab result and console.log, can you help me to solve this issue ?

**EDIT :** add source code

Contract service :

```
export const getContractData = (refContract) => {
  return axios.get(`${API_CONTRACT_URL}/contrats/${refContract}`)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      return response.data;
    });
};
```

Contract module :

```
import { getContractData as getContractDataApi } from '@/services/contrats';

const state = {
  contractData: {},
};

const mutations = {
  ['GET_CONTRACT_DATA_SUCCESS'](state, contractData) {
    state.contractData = contractData;
  },
  ['GET_CONTRACT_DATA_FAILURE'](state) {
    state.contractData = {};
  },
};

const actions = {
  getContractData({ commit }, refContract) {
    return getContractDataApi(refContract).then(
      contractData => commit('GET_CONTRACT_DATA_SUCCESS', contractData),
      error => commit('GET_CONTRACT_DATA_FAILURE', error),
    );
  },
};
```

Contract component :

```
<template>
  ...
  <v-text-field
    label="Référence du contrat"
    v-model="refContract"
    color="primary"
  />
  <div @click="synchroContractDatas()">
    Synchro données du contrat
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';

  ...

  synchroContractDatas() {
    if (this.refContract !== null) {
      this.getContractData(this.refContract).then(() => {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          ...
      }
    }
  },
</script>
```

Comment: It's maybe an issue about your use of async / promises functions. Nobody will be able to help you without a source code. Avoid printscreen image and prefer source code (in text).

Comment: I've added the source code

Comment: As I thought, it's probably about vuex. Bingo. You can add the tag `vuex` in your question. Look at StackOverflow anwsers [VueJs Async Api Data best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66510741/10489562) and [Async/Await with Vuex dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55701084/10489562) for `await` and `this.$store.dispatch` in vuex.

Comment: Thanks a lot, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) solved my problem.